# Bookdown Special Headers within Article Document Class

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Bookdown has introduced a ton of great functionality, but I am having some issues with the single document output option. When `documentclass:` in the YAML header is set to `book` bookdown has no trouble recognizing and creating special headers, but if `documentclass:` is set to `article` bookdown is unable to render special headers. Here is a brief example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "John Doe"
date: "November 10, 2016"
documentclass: article
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(bookdown)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Chapter One
# Chapter Two
# (APPENDIX) Appendix {-}
# Appendix A
# Appendix B
````

Is it possible to render documents of class `article` with special headers using Bookdown, or is this outside of Bookdown's functionality at this time?

Comment: I'll fix it. `article` should be supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have [updated](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/8fbb559b16c2f442d6a18dddcc14349b0c76311a) **bookdown** on Github so that the `article` class will also be supported when you use these special headers. Please try the latest version (>= 0.2):

```
install.packages('bookdown')
```

Comment: Hey Yihui with the new version of bookdown the appendices are rendered within the `article class`, but when you render using `html_documetn2` or `pdf_document2` the appendix figure numbers (Figure A.1, Figure A.2 etc) are not correctly rendered. Instead they are rendered as normal sections (Figure 5.1, 5.2 etc). Let me know if you want example.

Comment: @ForrestWilliams Thanks for the report! I have fixed this issue as well on Github:  https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/245 (you need to install from Github)

Comment: using Bookdown version 0.2.3 the issue is resolved for `html_document2`, thanks! florisvdh mentioned that this is not an issue for `pdf_document2` which is true for the appendix titles, but figure numbers still do not correctly render.

Comment: @ForrestWilliams Could you post a new question here or file an issue to bookdown with a reproducible example? I tested figures in appendix, and I didn't see anything wrong.

Comment: Here is the new quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678036/rendering-appendix-figure-numbers-in-bookdown